# postgres convert a substring to epoch

Tags: sql, postgresql, substring, epoch

I'm trying to convert a epoch timestamp to a human readable timestamp in a **single query** but I'm getting a little stuck - any help is appreciated.

```
testing=# SELECT creation_time FROM users LIMIT 1;
    creation_time    
---------------
 1354006445722
(1 row)

testing=# SELECT SUBSTRING('1498123813330', 1,10);
  SUBSTRING  
------------
 1498123813
(1 row)

testing=# SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + 1498123813 * INTERVAL '1 second';
        ?column?        
------------------------
 2017-06-22 02:30:13-07
(1 row)
```

Anyway to put this into a single query?

Comment: Is `created_time` stored as text?

Comment: @McNets 'header_timestamp'

Comment: @OtoShavadze - Sorry, updated now.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is `CAST`ing, i.e.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' +
         SUBSTRING(creation_time, 1, 10)::NUMERIC * INTERVAL '1 second';
```

**But**, if creating time is epoch milliseconds, you could do:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(creation_time::double precision / 1000)
```

instead, which will preserve milliseconds too. You can print timestamp out with [`to_char`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) if you want a format, other than the default timestamp output.

http://rextester.com/EHPNJ86308

Comment: When trying this I get `No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `created_time` is stored as a varchar, you can apply the same `substring` logic to it and cast it to a number:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + 
       SUBSTRING(creation_time, 1,10)::NUMERIC * INTERVAL '1 second'
FROM   users
```

Comment: When trying this I get `No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: What type is `creation_time`?

Comment: Type: `header_timestamp`